# How to color cells of jtable depending on cell's value

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to color some specific cells of a jtable. Here is my render class. I put sysout on the `if` blocks. All strings are printed but the color of cells didn't change except one of them.

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    static double rpmMin, rpmMax, speedMin, speedMax, temperatureMin, temperatureMax, voltageMin, voltageMax;


  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if (!table.isRowSelected(row)) {
        if (column == 2 && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) > rpmMin
                && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) < rpmMax) {
            c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        if(column == 3 && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) > speedMin
                && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) < speedMax){
            c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        if (column == 4 && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) > temperatureMin
                && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) < temperatureMax) {
            c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        if(column == 5 && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) > voltageMin
                && Double.parseDouble(value.toString()) < voltageMax){
            c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        else {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    return c;
  }
}
```

[Here is the output of my program. Only the first unsuitable value is colored pink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbQzj.png)

I prepared an excel to show the proper output.[Here is the picture that I expected to see as output of this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep1ko.png)

I don't know why it didn't work. Can somebody please explain it to me? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic trap. Your individual ifs are working fine, it's just that your last if is an if/else statement which will turn everything green unless it's suitably pink.

So basically, **the first 4 if statements are ignored** as only the last one determines whether it is green or pink.

Also, for sanity purposes, parse once, reuse twice or more.

```
    Double val = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());

    if (column == 2 && val > rpmMin
            && val < rpmMax) {
        c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }
    else if(column == 3 && val > speedMin
            && val < speedMax){
        c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }
    else if (column == 4 && val > temperatureMin
            && val < temperatureMax) {
        c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }
    else if(column == 5 && val > voltageMin
            && val < voltageMax){
        c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }
    else {
        c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

Comment: I typically don't like `switch` statements, but I think I would use one here.

Comment: @bradimus I didn't think of that, but yeah, `switch` on `column` would work, didn't notice that when cutting out all the parsing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking what I did wrong over two hours. I just realized the if statements. I exactly don't know why I used them in this way. Thanks again @Compass

Comment: All of the 'if' statements determine an integer column, then determine if 'val' is between two other values. The column value could be an index into an double-indexed array, where one dimension is indexed by the column number (or mapped to it), and the two values at that location are the min and max. If the value matches, you get pink, otherwise green. That would make this one if/else with an array.

Answer (score 1):

Or something like (not compiling this, please excuse roughness):

```
int [][] minMaxes = { {0, 0},
                      {0, 0},
                      {rpmMin, rpmMax},
                      {speedMin, speedMax},
                      {temperatureMin, temperatureMax},
                      {voltageMin, voltageMax}
                    };
Color bgColor;
if (val > minMaxes[column][0] && val < minMaxes[column][1])
{
  bgColor = PINK;
}
else
{
  bgColor = GREEN;
}
c.setBackGround(bgColor);
```

With appropriate checks on the value of column, etc.

**EDIT**

To prevent the errors cause of date and time string, I added one more if block to your code, and it worked perfectly. Here is the **getTableCellRendererComponent** method.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    double [][] minMaxes = { {0, 0},
            {0, 0},
            {rpmMin, rpmMax},
            {speedMin, speedMax},
            {temperatureMin, temperatureMax},
            {voltageMin, voltageMax}
          };
    if (!table.isRowSelected(row)) {
        if(column == 0 || column == 1){
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else if (Double.parseDouble(value.toString())>minMaxes[column][0] && Double.parseDouble(value.toString())<minMaxes[column][1]) {
            c.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }
        else {
            c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```